# How to register a custom Hibernate ARRAY Type that handles both real[] and text[] array column types

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-types

I am using the [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) library for custom Hibernate types.

I have two `CustomArrayType` that handle the `real[]` and `text[]` array types.

I am able to register one `CustomStringArrayType` in the Hibernate Dialect (e.g. `PostgreSQL94Dialect`) but how can register two types?

Below is my custom dialect without which I am getting Dialect Not Found 2003 Error:

```
public class HibernateCustomDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateCustomDialect.class);


    public HibernateCustomDialect() {
        super();
        log.info("Registering Custom Hibernate Dialect - {}", HibernateCustomDialect.class.getName());
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, CustomStringArrayType.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CustomStringArrayType` doesn't come from the [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) project. What you could do is use the [`ListArrayType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-array-java-list/), which is more generic and should handle both `real[]` and `text[]` while allowing you to use a `List` on the Java side:

```
@Entity(name = "Event")
@Table(name = "event")
@TypeDef(
    name = "list-array",
    typeClass = ListArrayType.class
)
public class Event {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @Type(type = "list-array")
    @Column(
        name = "sensor_ids",
        columnDefinition = "uuid[]"
    )
    private List<UUID> sensorIds;
 
    @Type(type = "list-array")
    @Column(
        name = "sensor_names",
        columnDefinition = "text[]"
    )
    private List<String> sensorNames;
 
    @Type(type = "list-array")
    @Column(
        name = "sensor_values",
        columnDefinition = "integer[]"
    )
    private List<Integer> sensorValues;
 
    @Type(type = "list-array")
    @Column(
        name = "sensor_long_values",
        columnDefinition = "bigint[]"
    )
    private List<Long> sensorLongValues;
 
    @Type(
        type = "com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.ListArrayType",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(
                name = ListArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE,
                value = "sensor_state"
            )
        }
    )
    @Column(
        name = "sensor_states",
        columnDefinition = "sensor_state[]"
    )
    private List<SensorState> sensorStates;
 
    @Type(type = "list-array")
    @Column(
        name = "date_values",
        columnDefinition = "date[]"
    )
    private List<Date> dateValues;
 
    @Type(type = "list-array")
    @Column(
        name = "timestamp_values",
        columnDefinition = "timestamp[]"
    )
    private List<Date> timestampValues;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: how to retrieve this sensorNames as a list and stream? for me it's coming as a single string, what to do?

Comment: @Vlad - It works but the Envers fails to audit it. I tried with text[]

EDIT - NVM. It works only if TypeDef name is exactly "list-array"